# Increment every element after inserted item in list

Tags: python

I have two lists that I need to keep in sync with one another. The example below is a very stripped down version of the full application.

`list_1` contains data, `list_2` contains index values.

```
list_1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
list_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now I want to `.insert()` into `list_1` - at any index - and keep list two in sync. That means if I insert an element at index 1 so that it looks like this:

```
list_1 = ['item1', 'new_item!', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
```

I know the index in this case is `1` so I can insert that at the proper point in `list_2`

```
list_2 = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
#            ^----- Newly inserted index
```

My question is, how can I efficiently update every element after this inserted value to increment by 1?

---

I realize this is very basic and unwarranted for this example, but for the full application, these two lists are needed and the `list_2` of indexes is used to control a PyQt UI. Changing for this two list solution would be incredibly time consuming at this point.

Comment: Isn't `list_2` always just `list(range(len(list_1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, but anyway...

You can mutate `list_2` like this:

```
list_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3]

val = 1
idx = 1

list_2.insert(idx, val)
print(list_2)

list_2[idx+1:] = [u+1 for u in list_2[idx+1:]]
print(list_2)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Because we use slice assignment we're mutating the original `list_2` object rather than replacing it, so if any other objects have references to `list_2` they will see the changes.